# Using APACHE REWRITE To Force A Specific Directory To Be HTTPS (.htaccess)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have tried using some rewrite to make my "PhpMyAdmin" page https instead of http. I would force https on all of my pages except for the fact that I have a very unique setup going on.

The directory that I have tried to force https on is named "hiddenpma", Here is what I have tried:

```
#Enable Rewrite Engine
RewriteEngine On

#Force HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http
RewriteRule ^(hiddenpma/.*)$ https://w5unt.ga/hiddenpma/$1 [R=301,L]
```

You can actually go visit the site for proof that it doesnt work. you can go there at this location: https://w5unt.ga/hiddenpma/. Google chrome is labeling my php my admin page as "dangerous" and therefore not letting my login, I believe that it is because it is http and not https. Any thoughts? Thanks[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fRvsc.png)

Comment: (Incidentally, my Chrome doesn't label that page as dangerous.)

Comment: Right, so you have to actually try to login, but anyways, I am providing a smtp video feed to my viewers and it requires certain pages to be http an others to be https.

Comment: By capturing `(hiddenpma/.*)` and then appending it like `https://w5unt.ga/hiddenpma/$1`, you are “doubling” your `hiddenpma` folder, the resulting URL will be `https://w5unt.ga/hiddenpma/hiddenpma/foo`

Comment: Hide your PHPMyAdmin page, just for security. I just realised it is available to everybody. Ask me if you don't know how to hide it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create .htaccess inside the folder which you want to be https and put this code inside it:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

The dangerous error that chrome gives might be because your ssl cert might not be valid.

Comment: Hey there, forgot to mark this as the correct answer, thanks for your help.

Comment: @AustinLeath No problem.